# Undefined Symbols for Architecture x86-64"start"

Tags: c++, macos, g++

How can I link my program?

I have a mid 2012 macbook pro which I recently upgraded to OSX 10.11 (El Capitan). In order to compile c++ programs I had to reinstall g++ which I did using brew.

Now I am getting an error when trying to link my program.

> g++-6 -o hello hello.o
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "start", referenced from:
>        implicit entry/start for main executable
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Here is my code: hello.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout<<"Beginning program";
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output when I link with the -v flag

> g++-6 -o hello hello.o -v

Using built-in specs.

COLLECT_GCC=g++-6

COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0/lto-wrapper

Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0

Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-6 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --with-build-config=bootstrap-debug --disable-werror --with-pkgversion='Homebrew gcc 6.2.0' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues --enable-plugin --disable-nls --enable-multilib

Thread model: posix

gcc version 6.2.0 (Homebrew gcc 6.2.0)

COMPILER_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/

LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0/:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0/../../../

COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-o' 'hello' '-v' '-mmacosx-version-min=10.11.3' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=core2'
 /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0/collect2 -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.11.3 -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak -o hello -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0 -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0/../../.. hello.o -lstdc++ -no_compact_unwind -lSystem -lgcc_ext.10.5 -lgcc -lSystem -v
collect2 version 6.2.0
/usr/bin/ld -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.11.3 -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak -o hello -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0 -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0/../../.. hello.o -lstdc++ -no_compact_unwind -lSystem -lgcc_ext.10.5 -lgcc -lSystem -v
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-136
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s i386 x86_64

Library search paths:
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0/6.2.0
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/6.2.0/lib/gcc/6
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib

Framework search paths:
    /Library/Frameworks/
    /System/Library/Frameworks/

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "start", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I've read from other posts that this might be a problem with the default libraries being compiled by an older version of g++. But I think that isn't the problem here because the library search paths seem to point g++ towards g++-6's libraries.

Comment: why don't you use clang++?

Comment: Hi. I get the same error with clang++:
clang++ hello.cpp                                                                                 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "start", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)